# Facebook Page Plugin not showing in FireFox

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, blogger

I run a small film and TV review blog through Google's Blogger service that contains a Facebook Page Plugin that allows users on the site to "Like" my page.

However, I recently realised that it wasn't displaying in FireFox, as far as I can tell, but I *can* see it in Internet Explorer and Google Chrome.

The Java SDK is in the correct place under the `<body>` tag, as per the documentation.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Below is the code for the plug-in itself, contained within one of the Blogger "gadgets", a HTML/JavaScript box.

```
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/ScreenNerds" data-width="250" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="false" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true" data-show-posts="false">
  <div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
    <blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/ScreenNerds">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/ScreenNerds">Screen Nerds</a>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: Assuming that you are talking about http://screennerds.blogspot.de/ – works fine for me in Firefox, the page plugin shows up on top in the right sidebar. Perhaps you are using some extension that blocks social plugins.

Comment: @CBroe I have Ad-Block, but it is disabled on my blog.

Comment: @CBroe After completely disabling both the Add Ons I have for FireFox, the Facebook Page Plug-in still does not appear.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue you are describing (in Firefox). Please add more details, such as any errors you observe in your JS console, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try Disable Tracking Protection on Firefox?

[image: Firefox - Tracking Protection]